# How To Dynamically Request Access Token Using Passport And Laravel

Tags: laravel, oauth, multi-tenant, laravel-passport

I am working with a multi-tenant setup and I am looking for a way that when I attempt to request access tokens I can send the request to the correct login end point.

For instance in a single tenant set up when I make a request for a access_token it would look something like this

```
$http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

    try {
        $response = $http->post('http://mydomain.test/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => env('CLIENT_ID'),
                'client_secret' => env('CLIENT_SECRET'),
                'username' => $request->username,
                'password' => $request->password,
                ]
                ]);

                return response()->getBody();
            }
```

Now what I am trying to do is make the login end point $http->post(my url) to change depending on the tenant user making the request.

So currently when I make a post request to the login controller I have the route wrapped in a middle ware like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'tenancy.enforce'], function () {
    Route::post('/login', 'PassportTokenController@login');
});
```

and then in my controller I can call the client secret and the fqdn based on the tenant requesting the information

So when I ask for the fqdn of the request being made and the client_secret from the database of the tenant I will get the correct data

```
$passport = DB::table('oauth_clients')->where('id', 2)->first(); 

$hostname  = app(\Hyn\Tenancy\Environment::class)->hostname();
```

now if I insert these variables into the login method I will get an 500 internal server error

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $passport = DB::table('oauth_clients')->where('id', 2)->first(); 

        $hostname  = app(\Hyn\Tenancy\Environment::class)->hostname();

        $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

        try {
            $response = $http->post('http://' . $hostname->fqdn . '/oauth/token', [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => 2,
                    'client_secret' => $passport->secret,
                    'username' => $request->username,
                    'password' => $request->password,
                    ]
                    ]);

                    return response()->getBody();
                } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
                    if ($e->getCode() === 400) {
                        return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or a password.', $e->getCode());
                    } else if ($e->getCode() === 401) {
                        return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
            }
            return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server.', $e->getCode());
        }

    }
```

Notice the `$http->post(my url)` changes depending on the tenant user making the request.

Is there something with passport I should be doing so that I can dynamically make the request for the oauth access token?

*Update so after figuring out how to get an actual server error response I am noticing that the Guzzle http is trying to query the system database instead of the tenant database

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'multitenant-diy.oauth_clients' doesn't exist (SQL: select * f (truncated...)
 in C:\laragon\www\multitenant-diy\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113
```

Comment: I request that instead of creating separate endpoints, you can use client_id to tag tenant with it. Because the current solution is complex and you can achieve the same by doing that.

Comment: Please also share 500 error message for reference so I can better guide you.

Comment: @MuhammadUsama, Thank you for the reply! So as far as the 500 error message, I cannot figure out a way for guzzlehttp to return an actualy response with the 500 message. If you look at the bottom of the post, where it says `return response()->json('Something went wrong on server', $eg->getCode());` That is the only thing returned as far as a message. When I remove that I get nothing. Could you please elaborate more on your first comment?? Thank you!

Comment: Could you please explain why you need a different route for each tenant? If you like to identify tenant against each request then you can access through `auth()->user()->Token()->getAttribute('client_id');` and you can save that client_id in relation to tenant.

Comment: @MuhammadUsama, that is because the package I am using with laravel to make it multi-tenant requires the use of the `fqdn` so it knows for which tenant you are making requests for. I just need to understand what the `oauth/token` endpoint is acutally doing? each tenant database contains the client_id and client_secret so why could I not use the `fqdn` to make this request??

Comment: @MuhammadUsama, so i figured out how to get an acutall 500 response and it is obviously trying to query my system database instead of my tenant data base. I will post the alarm in the original question at the bottom.

Comment: Great, Do let me know if you still required help.

Comment: Actually I am able to create token for each tenant but while authenticating via `auth:api` I am getting response as `{"message":"Unauthenticated."}`